# Python Creating a file that returns n, number, of 8-bit binary strings

Tags: python, file, binary

Currently this is what my python code looks like. I am trying to write a file that will return the number, n, 8-bit binary strings, but I am stuck because the file is returning the correct number of binary strings but they are not random within the string. ie. 00000000 or 11111111.

```
import random

def eightBitStrings(n):

    eightBits = "eightBits.txt"
    outputFile = open(eightBits,"w")


    for element in range(n):

        randomNum = int(random.random()*2)

        randomNum = str(randomNum) * 8

        outputFile.write(str(randomNum)+"\n")        


    outputFile.close()
```

Any suggestions are appreciated thank you!

Comment: The line `randomNum = str(randomNum) * 8` merely repeats eight times the same character.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import random

with open('eightBits.txt', 'w') as output_file:    
    for _ in range(n):
        random_num = random.randrange(255)
        output_file.write('{:08b}\n'.format(random_num))
```

Instead of creating a string bit by bit, you can generate a number in the [0, 255] range, and convert that to binary instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you cast to an `int`.

`random()` returns a value between 0 and 1.  Multiply those values by 2 and you've expanded your range to [0,2).

However, when you convert those floats to ints, you lose the decimals and so now you are only capable of generating 0s and 1s.

Then when you do `str(randomNum)*8`, you are just making a string that contains 8 of whatever `randomNum` is, which is either 0 or 1.

If you want to keep your current code, you simply need an extra loop to generate 8 random numbers between 0 and 1.  That's why you end up with strings that are either 8 0s or 8 1s

```
import random

def eightBitStrings(n):
    eightBits = "eightBits.txt"
    outputFile = open(eightBits,"w")

    for element in range(n):
        # create our string and we will randomly select 0 or 1 eight times
        s = ""
        for _ in range(8):
            # randomly generate 0 or 1 and append to our string
            randomNum = int(random.random()*2)
            s = s + str(randomNum)

        # output to file
        outputFile.write(s+"\n")        

    outputFile.close()
```

Another way would be to use list comprehension and `random.randint()` (which generates integers within a given range):

```
import random

def eightBitStrings(n):
    eightBits = "eightBits.txt"
    outputFile = open(eightBits,"w")

    for element in range(n):
       #join together 8 randomly selected integers between [0,1]
       randomNumber = "".join([str(random.randint(0,1)) for _ in range(8)])
       outputFile.write(randomNumber+"\n")
    outputFile.close()
```